# AWS RDS decouple from Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does anyone knows why I get this error when trying to decouple my RDS from my env ??

I get this 2 errors :

DB Allocated storage should be more than the previous value.

RDS DB Engine option setting is not allowed to changed

Also I just did it till 2 days ago when AWS UI got updated with the brilliant idea to make it look less appealing .

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this btw? I'm having the exact same issue...

Comment: I have the same problem exactly before the AWS team changed the UI in elasticbeanstalk.
Did you solve it ?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue - I've filed an issue on the AWS EB roadmap Github here: https://github.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk-roadmap/issues/291

LOL'd at OP's bit about the UI. Thought the exact same thing